# How to manage password during update user profile in Yii2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I can add user successfully, For Password hashing I am using `md5()` But when I update user it is giving an error.

Here are the model rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'group_user','status'], 'required'],
        ['email','email'],
        [['confirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password','on'=>'create'],
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm', ], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

In the form i.e. View, I am using following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
    if($case == 'create') { //this condition called when create user 
        echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput([
            'maxlength' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Enter the Password',
        ]);
    }
    else { // during update
        echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput([
            'maxlength' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Enter the Password',
            'value' => '',
        ]);
    }
?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'confirm')->passwordInput([
        'maxlength' => true,
        'placeholder' => 'Confirm Password',
    ]) ?>   
</div>
```

and in controller I am using following code:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $case = "update";
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'all_users_array' => $all_users_array,
            'all_groups_array' => $all_groups_array,
            'case' => $case,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Undefined offset: 1 Failed to prepare SQL: UPDATE `xbox_user` SET
>   `password`=:qp0, `role`=:qp1, `modified`=:qp2, `status`=:qp3 WHERE
>   `id`=:qp4

Can anyone please let me what code should be modified there?

Thank you!

Comment: remove `password ` from required list in rules. `[['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email',  'role', 'group_user','status'], 'required'],`

Comment: I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: show `create ` and `update` action.

Comment: I have updated code, please check

Comment: Do you want to allow password to be changed in update action?

Comment: yes this is for sub user. So if empty then ignore else repeat validations and required validation will apply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132997/discussion-between-981-and-insane-skull).

Comment: Dont use  like   $case = "update";   use this $this->isNewRecord();

Comment: Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::isNewRecord()

Comment: $model->isNewRecord();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `scenarios` in your case and use rules() too for other requirements, In `Users.php` model file write the following code:

```
public function scenarios(){
  $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
  $scenarios['create'] = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'group_user','status', 'password','confirm'];
  $scenarios['update'] = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'group_user','status'];
  return $scenarios;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'group_user','status', 'password','confirm'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'unique' ],
        ['email', 'unique' ,'targetAttribute' => 'email'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\Users', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
        ['confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>"Passwords does not match." ],
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm', ], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

In your views file use the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <?php
  if($case == 'create'){
    echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder'=>'Enter the Password']);
  }
  else{
    echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder'=>'Enter the Password']);
 }
?>   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'confirm')->passwordInput(['maxlength' =>true,'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password']) ?>   
 </div>
```

and in your controller file, `UsersController.php` use the following code:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
  $model = $this->findModel($id);

  $model->scenario = 'update'; // calling scenario of update
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $req_array = yii::$app->request->post();
        $role  = $req_array['Users']['role'][0];

        $model->role = $role;
        if($req_array['Users']['password'] !== $req_array['Users']['confirm'])
        {
          $model->addError('confirm','Password and Confirm should be same.');
          $model->password = $req_array['Users']['password'];
          $model->confirm = $req_array['Users']['confirm'];
          return $this->render('update', [
              'model' => $model,
              'all_users_array'=>$all_users_array,
              'all_groups_array'=>$all_groups_array,
              'case'=>$case,
          ]);
        }
        elseif( ($req_array['Users']['password'] == $req_array['Users']['confirm']) && (!empty($req_array['Users']['password'])))
        {
          $model->password = MD5($req_array['Users']['password']);
          $model->save();
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else
        {

          $model->save();
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
      } else {
          $model->password = '';
          return $this->render('update', [
              'model' => $model,
              'all_users_array'=>$all_users_array,
              'all_groups_array'=>$all_groups_array,
              'case'=>$case,
          ]);
      }
    }
```

Using this code, you will not get error of required password in update, In case if you fill the password then process of confirm password and required will be run.
Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 2):

**User Model**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'role', 'group_user','status'], 'required'],
        ['email','email'],
        [['password', 'confirm'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],

        ['confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message'=>"Passwords does not match." ],
        [['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm', ], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

**Update Action**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->passowrd = '';
    $model->confirm = '';

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->role = $model->role[0]; 
        if (empty($model->password) || empty($model->confirm)) {
            $model->password = $model->getOldAttribute('password');
            $model->confirm = $model->getOldAttribute('confirm');
        }
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'all_users_array'=>$all_users_array,
            'all_groups_array'=>$all_groups_array,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder'=>'Enter the Password']) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'confirm')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password']) ?>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First try this one

```
[['confirm'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password','on'=>'create']
```

if not work then please follow the following steps create your scenario for updation and don't compare password
Did you try scenarios.. i will give a simple example for user registration and user login i hope it will help you

```
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name','email','password'],'required'],
            ['email','email'],
            [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'register'],
            ];
    }
    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['login'] = ['name','password'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
        return $scenarios;
    }
}
?>
```

**Apply Scenario For Model**
See the below code, We added two ways of setting the scenario of a model. By default, scenario will support the model rules.

```
<?php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    // APPLY SCENARIOS
    // scenario is set as a property
    public function  actionLogin(){
        $model = new User;
        $model->scenario = 'login';
    }
    // scenario is set through configuration
    public function  actionRegister(){
        $model = new User(['scenario' => 'register']);
    }
}
?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: error coming during password and confirm password mismatch

Answer (score 1):

I have my own basic User model i reuse for most projects, which handles updating new password or leaving the previous one if no password is provided by the update form. Also implements `IdentityInterface` so it can be used for login to the Application.

My basic User model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';

    // We use $hash to save the hashed password we already have saved in the DB
    public $hash;
    public $password_repeat;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios() {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_LOGIN] = ['user', 'password'];
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['user', 'password', 'password_repeat', 'email', 'authKey'];
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_UPDATE] = ['user', 'password', 'password_repeat', 'email'];
        return $scenarios;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['user'], 'string', 'max' => 45],

            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['email'], 'email'],

            [['password', 'password_repeat'], 'string', 'max' => 60],

            [['authKey'], 'string', 'max' => 32],

            [['user', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
            [['user', 'password', 'password_repeat', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE],
            [['user', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_UPDATE],

            // Generate a random String with 32 characters to use as AuthKey
            [['authKey'], 'default', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE, 'value' => Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString()],

            [['password'], 'compare', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE, 'skipOnEmpty' => true],

            [['user'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'Id',
            'user' => 'User',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'authKey' => 'AuthKey',
            'email' => 'Email',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if($insert) {
                $this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
            }
            else {
                if(strlen($this->password) > 0) {
                    $this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
                }
                else {
                    $this->password = $this->hash;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function afterFind() {
        $this->hash = $this->password;
        $this->password = '';
        parent::afterFind();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        return self::findOne($id);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        $model = static::findOne(['user' => $username]);
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->hash);
    }
}
```

This way you only need to use the corresponding `scenario` in your `create`, `update` and `login` actions:

```
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_LOGIN;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CREATE;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
```